# Saving CSV file such that its name is itself a string

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, zip

My code is about getting sensor values and appending them in csv file. This csv file gets too long and I want to compress it in zip file after 1000 lines. For this I want my csv file to be saved with filename as `Logger1` for the first time and after this `logger1` file has crossed 1000 lines it should be converted into zip file, and removed while `'i'` gets incremented by 1.Now after this, the further data should be  saved in the csv file with  filename as logger2. How do I add `'i'` along with the file name. I tried using `str(i)` but it didn't work as the filename is in the inverted commas itself.

```
export_csv = x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/Logger + str(i).csv', 
             index = None, mode='a', header=False)
input_file = open("Logger + str(i).csv","r+")
reader_file = csv.reader(input_file)
l = len(list(reader_file))
if (l > 1000) :
 jungle_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('Logger + str(i).zip', 
              'w')
 jungle_zip.write('Logger + str(i).csv', 
                  compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
 jungle_zip.close()
 os.remove("Logger + str(i).csv")
 i +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
'Logger' + str(i) + '.zip'
```

instead of

```
'Logger + str(i).zip'
```

bceause str(i) is not considered a function in the string